# Selecting rows of data based on IDs

Tags: r

The data set I'm working with has 13 columns with the following headers (bold), and 302 rows : **id:** 001, 002,..., 302), **source_code:** : AAA, BBB, CCC, **date**,**day**, **month**, **year**, **time**,**hour**, **minute**, **second**,**latitude**, **longitude**, **inscriptions:** NA, 1 or 0.

I have a script that creates density maps using this dataset, however, I want to be able to use filters that select the data I want the maps to include and exclude.

***example 1:*** I want to ONLY select the data with **id** = 1-123  ( and name this selection of data: *data_A*)

***example 2:*** I want to ONLY select the data with **id** = 124-168 (and name this: *data_B* )

***example 3:*** I want to ONLY select the data with **id** = 1-168 (and name this: *data_AB* )

***example 4:*** I want to ONLY select the data where **id** = 169-302 (name this: *data_C*)

***example 5:*** I want to ONLY select the data where **id** = 3 (name this: *data_3*)

I am new using Rstudio and this platform to ask questions, so sorry beforehand if this explanation is vague!

**Thank you!!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `%in%` to subset the 'id' based on the range of sequence (`:`) and create new objects

```
id1 <- as.numeric(data$id)
data_A <- data[id1 %in% 1:123,]
data_B <- data[id1 %in% 124:168,]
data_AB <- data[id1 %in% 1:168,]
data_C <- data[id1%in% 169:302,]
data_3 <- data[id1 == 3,]
```

---

Or if we want to keep the range also as string

```
data_A <- data[data$id %in% sprintf('%03d', 1:123),]
data_B <- data[data$id %in% sprintf('%03d', 124:168),]
```

Comment: @neussegura i would consider converting to numeric.  Please check my update. thanks

Comment: as the **id**s are 3 digit numbers (001, 002,..., 010, 011,..., 301, 302), I modified your script to : `id1 <- as.numeric(data$id)` , `data_A <- data[id1 %in% 001:123,]` , 
`data_B <- data[id1 %in% 124:168,]` , `data_AB <- data[id1 %in% 001:168,]`,
`data_C <- data[Id1 %in% 169:302,]`,
`data_3 <- data[id1 == 003,] ` It worked perfectly fine! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: @neussegura now, you don't need `001:123` instead it is just `1:123` because numeric values doesn't pad 0s at the beginning.  it is only for strings, we have the padding at the beginning. i.e. `str1 <- '001'; as.numeric(str1)`

Comment: is there a way I can keep `001:302` instead of `1:302` ?  Because I match this dataset with another one with the same IDs after running these filters :)

Comment: @neussegura If you check my code, I am not changing your originaal 'id' column.  It just remains the same.  If you want to change the range, then one option is `sprintf('%03d', 1:302)`

Comment: You are **amaaaazing** !! I've tried all the different ways you have proposed, and using ``data_A <- data[data$id %in% sprintf('%03d', 1:123),]`` ,
``data_B <- data[data$id %in% sprintf('%03d', 124:168),]`` is the best choice!! I have tried doing ``data_AB <- data[data$id %in% sprintf('%03d', 1:168),]``
``data_C <- data[data$id %in% sprintf('%03d', 169:302),]``,
``data_id3 <- data[data$id %in% sprintf('%03d', 3),]`` and they also work! THANK YOU SO MUCH

Answer (score 1):

Please always include a [reproducible minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this makes it a lot easier to help you!  Especially using `GNU R` this is [relatively](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/) [easy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

From what I understand the [`filter`-function](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/filter.html) in [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/) (or [`poorman`](https://nathaneastwood.github.io/poorman/)) can accomplish this for you.  I wrote an example where you can filter according to the `id`-column.

```
library(dplyr)

df <-
  data.frame(c(1,2,3,4,5),
             c("a","b","c","d","e"),
             c(NA,0,1,NA,0))

colnames(df) <- c("id","letter","0or1")

df %>%
  dplyr::filter(id <= 3)
```

Comment: Thank you! I used the answer from @akrun :)